# Querying on Household Income ranges in a dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, esri-geodatabase, select-by-attribute, sorting

I've recently been assigned a project to create an ArcGIS database to hold responses from a survey which will be used to perform analysis on the data. One column requires me to enter a dollar-range for household income. The possible ranges are:

- 25,000 //for > $25,000
- 25,000-49,000
- 50,000-99,000
- 100,000-149,000
- 150,000-199,000
- 200,000 //for >$200,000

When trying to select by attributes, for example

```
Select * From Respondent Where HHI > '150,000-199,000'
```

everything is returned ***except*** for the 100,140,000 and 150,000-199,000 ranges is returned.

This makes sense because it's not less than or equal to. I'm more familiar with regular SQL, not esri's version, however I'm thinking it's not matching the full range, and just performing the > operation on the first character in the range (or hanging on the -), and since the ASCII value is less than that of other ranges, 25,000-49,000, for instance, they are assumed to be greater than the initial query 150,000-199,000.

Does anyone know a way to properly select on these? This has had me stumped for a while now.

Edit: Here's an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCbFD.png) image showing how the data is entered into the specific column.

Comment: Oh I see what you're doing... you have text values describing ranges... so you can't use a numeric operator on a) a string and b) a string of ranges. You'll have to be very specific in your string operators... (sorry, please disregard my previous answer)

Comment: Can you shed any light into how I would go about this? I don't think there's any one good data type to hold ranges, which is why I ended up keeping it as a string.

Comment: Make your household income a numeric field then you can use the > operator. The Esri SQL is dependant on the underlying database, for example the mod operator in one is *mod(field,number) = value* and in another it's *field mod number = value*. If you cannot modify the database perhaps try *Cast* as in *cast(income,INTEGER) > 199000* to turn the strings into numbers on the fly beware: non-numeric returns (like "$29,990.") don't cast to INTEGER so you will have to get rid of anything that's not 0 to 9.

Comment: One way would be to setup a coded value domain using a short integer. So 0 would be 25,000 //for > $25,000, 1 would be 25,000-49,000, etc. Then you could at least query them that way.

Comment: That would be one way @ian, provided the data is already in ranges, it just depends on the question that was originally asked. It would make more sense if the question was 'what range is your household income in?', I was expecting *exact* values but that (on reflection) doesn't make much sense as people don't like giving that kind of information out.

Comment: @ian I tried making my case to use coded domains with my boss but it was insisted that this way worked, and up until today it hadn't been tested by anyone actually doing the analysis. I'm just going to go ahead and make an executive decision. Thanks for the help guys!